# Pass NON Latinic Characters In URL

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass non latinic characters to mvc controller. But the value is always `"??????"`. This is what I have. Any idea how to pass such type of value to controller parameter ?

Script

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'FOV/MCI/Cars?model=Ферари',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('error');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });
```

C#:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Cars(string model)
        {
           //here model is with value ??????
        }
```

Comment: You need to set the contenttype in the ajax request contentType: "charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your query string, such as using encodeURI to encode whole url or encodeURIComponent on query string:

```
$.ajax({
        url: encodeURI('FOV/MCI/Cars?model=Ферари'),
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```